# getCallbackTokenAsync returns "An internal error has occurred"

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

I have created an Outlook add-in, which uses `mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()` function to authenticate with EWS API. For the majority of the add-in users, this works without issues.

However, for some users, calling this function results in the `"An internal error has occurred"` error. This seems to occur just once, and subsequent calls to this function return token successfully.

Users that experience issues use various Outlook versions - Outlook 16.0.6965.2115, Outlook 16.0.7571.2109, Outlook Mac 15.29, ...

Do you have any idea what is the cause of this error?

Comment: We experience similar issues!

Comment: I haven't seen this problem, so I'm not sure what to suggest. It would be good to get some forensic data so we can investigate, but it sounds like you cannot reliably reproduce the error? If you can reproduce it, a Fiddler trace (or some other network trace) from the client would be helpful.