# getCallbackTokenAsync returns message "internal error has occurred”

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I develop add-in on premises, using Office.js's getCallbackTokenAsync to load the token.
But starting from yesterday, that function stopped working and returns a message "An internal error has occurred" error.

We tried on
Outlook 2016 16.0.4266.1001 and Outlook  2019 16.0.10338.20019
and behaviour is the same.

There is a very similar problem here: [getCallbackTokenAsync returns "An internal error has occurred"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855014/getcallbacktokenasync-returns-an-internal-error-has-occurred)

I also checked requests to exchange server and no errors found.
Here what Exchange server returned: https://www.screencast.com/t/HZkG88uE

Could you pls help me to figure out what can be cause of such behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a AD user logging in directly to their own mailbox, or a AD user logging in to  a mailbox that they have permission to?  Is it a cross-forest scenario (account forest / resource forest), or just a single forest?  Does this affect Desktop Outlook only, or also Outlook in a web browser?

Comment: Thanks for providing the the Fiddler info. The error returned by the server, "The token for this extension could not be retrieved.", helps but can have multiple causes. First, I would double-check that all of the "Items" in the response contain this error as the response can contain multiple tokens. Since you mentioned it was working in your environment recently, was there a recent configuration change in the Exchange environment, which may be related to this (or an invalid/expired certificate)? As Brian also suggested, can you check if the API succeeds when called from OWA?

Comment: Thank you for quick response.

Sorry for not adding all the info...

AD user is logging to his account. 
Cannot say for sure about scenario for a while.
It affects add-in on premises on both Desktop and OWA.

All items in response has the same values.
Certificate has to be valid.

We will recheck what is changed in configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: We have one exchange server that serves 2 domains on the same LAN(single forest).
I rechecked what have changed recently, and it seems that nothing has changed.

I call 2 methods.
1. Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(callback);
Result.status is succeeded, but value is empty.
https://www.screencast.com/t/ORDT4kTe25
Not sure if it affects on response, but in request payload Exchange 2013 is mentioned, while we have Exchange 2016.

2. Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(callback2);
Result.status is failed with error "internal error has occurred”

Thanks

Comment: Seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305330/office-api-call-to-getuseridentitytokenasync-returns-a-null-token is exactly the same issue

Unfortunately it ended up without an answer.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your server side logs for getClientAccessToken call? It should be in a directory like following: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\v15\Logging\Ews" with file name as getClientAccessTokenLogs.log on the server

Comment: Could you pls specify email address where I can send an email with logs to.

BTW: on the 13.12.2018 the procedure for replacing an expiring certificate was applied: http://byronwright.blogspot.com/2018/05/expired-microsoft-exchange-server-auth.html

Comment: That information is really helpful. It is quite possible that the certs weren't renewed properly. Could you try/retry the following:

1.  Create new self-signed certificate using New-ExchangeCertificate cmdlet [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/encryption-and-certificates/new-exchangecertificate?view=exchange-ps]

2. Modify the authorization configuration using Set-AuthConfig cmdlet to set thumbprint and publish the certificate created in step #1 [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/set-authconfig?view=exchange-ps]

Comment: Thank you!
The certificate was ok, however renewal has been made again using "Renew" link.
https://www.screencast.com/t/a3j7xgnWfwQS. However, not sure it does the same as you suggested.

Is there anywhere(CU notes) information about fixes for Exchange versions, mentioned there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546534/call-to-getuseridentitytokenasync-returning-a-null-token?rq=1

Thanks

Comment: Did renewing the certs solve your problem?

Comment: Hi guys.

Renewing the certificate solved the problem.
Thanks!